# Choose Edge->Vertex based on largest Edge property value

Tags: gremlin

I'm new to Gremlin and Graph DBs, I cannot figure this out yet.

I have `V(part) -> E(version) ver: 1..n -> V(attributes)`.
My vertex 'part' can have multiple out edges 'version', with different 'ver' property starting from 1 to n, pointing to different vertex 'attributes'. For instance 'part a' might have two 'version' edges, one with property ver 1 and the other ver 2, each edge point to a different vertex.

For each 'part' in my graph, or just for one, I need to fetch the 'attributes' vertex connected with the highest edge property 'ver' value.

```
g.addV("part").property("pn", 'p1').as('p').
addV("attributes").property("description", 'Part 1').as('a').
addE('version').property('ver', 1).from('p').to('a')

g.V().has('pn', 'p1').as('p).
addV("attributes").property("description", 'A better Part 1').as('a').
addE('version').property('ver', 2).from('p').to('a')
```

The logic should be applicable to more complex graphs.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Andrew

**Solution,** thanks to HadoopMarc.

```java
g.V().hasLabel('part').
local(outE('version').
      order().
        by('ver',desc).
      limit(1)).
inV().
path().
toList()
```

Comment: You can use the example for the order() step using local(), as listed in: https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#local-step

Answer (score 1):

Copying the discussion and updated question to an answer so that others can easily spot the solution. The `local` step allows (for each starting vertex) the required edge (with the most recent version) to be found:

```java
g.V().hasLabel('part').
local(outE('version').
      order().
        by('ver',desc).
      limit(1)).
inV().
path().
toList()
```